# Remove add and edit functionality in magento 1 grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, order-grid, edit, view

I want to remove the **Add New** button and edit functionality when row is clicked. I've followed [this](http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified) tutorial. I've got all the features as guided in the tutorial. But in my case this grid table must be viewable only. Instead of edit I would like to have a detail viewing page. The grid is as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the **add** button add this to `Foo_Bar_Block_Adminhtml_Baz::__construct()`

```
public function __construct()
{
    // The blockGroup must match the first half of how we call the block, and controller matches the second half
    // ie. foo_bar/adminhtml_baz
    $this->_blockGroup = 'myname_mygateway';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_mycontroller';
    $this->_headerText = $this->__('My Orders');
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_removeButton('add');

}
```

To make grid row unclickable change `Foo_Bar_Block_Adminhtml_Baz_Grid` from

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    // This is where our row data will link to
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
}
```

to

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return false;
}
```

To link to your detailed view change the controller action ...

```
public function getRowUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/yourAction', array('id' => $row->getId()));
}
```

Comment: Hello @sv3n , `return false` from `getRowUrl($row)`   does the trick of being unclickable and changing action changes the page accordingly. But `$this->_removeButton('add');` is doing nothing. Could I be making mistake. This is  my first time working with magento 1. So please help me in this.

Comment: Add button got remove by placing above code in my constructo after parent constructor. Cheers mate.